# How can i figure out if a process builder contains apex class call?

Tags: apex, soql, process-builder, tooling-api

I have a lot of processes in my org. I have a requirement to list the processes which are calling an apex class i.e- If a process builder consists of an immediate action which is calling an apex class method. It is very difficult for me to one by one check each process and declares the result. I was wondering if we have a soql tooling API query which could help me out. Any solution either in terms of configuration, Soql or apex will be appreciated. My goal is to filter out 20 processes out of 50 which have an apex class call in them.

Comment: you could certainly use an IDE and do a search on the Flow metadata object

Comment: This isn't possible with GA, off-the-shelf functionality, like plain Tooling API SOQL in the DevConsole or Apex. If you are/were in the [`MetadataComponentDepency` pilot](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.214.0.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_metadatacomponentdependency.htm), then you could use that. You could install the [Tooling API Apex Wrapper](https://github.com/afawcett/apex-toolingapi) and then query the list of Processes then requery each with its `Metadata` and look for `apexSelection`. But searching across downloaded metadata is going to be easiest.

Answer (score 3):

if your using any IDE, you get easily what flows are using apex classes.

1. Get flows files in to your local by using package.xml, we used VScode IDE

   **package.xml**

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
       <Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
           <types>
               <members>*</members>
               <name>Flow</name>
           </types>
           <version>45.0</version>
       </Package>
   ```
2. Once you get all files search with **`apexSelection`** keyword in your IDE local files, so it 'll give all flow files which are used Apex classes.

Comment: If you don't have and don't want to install an IDE, you could use this package.xml to extract the metadata using [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php), and then expand the zip and use your OS's search function to find `apexSelection` in the files.